# How would I connect to a mysql database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have [read](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) that PHP is obsoleting the MySql functions.

How will we connect to MySql database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you hear that?  I think it would be a great idea, but it's news to me.

It's better to use [`new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database')`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php)

Or (even better) use [`new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=hostname', 'username', 'password')`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: It was supposed to be deprecated, it was even in the manual, but they must have reversed that decision because i dont see any mention of it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the link @seriousdev. That's great news. Yeah, the mysql extension is used so widely there's no way they could really deprecate it or throw notices. But it's appropriate to encourage people to use the more feature-rich extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the new [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) classes.

Answer (score 1):

The new, better way of doing it is to use PDO. You can find pretty of examples on the web if you Google for ["php mysql pdo"](http://www.google.ca/search?q=pdo%20php%20mysql), [here is one](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO (PHP Data Objects)

example.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```